# Optimizing indexes for large PostgreSQL table

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I have a large table (location_history) with `uid` and `geohash`, and they are both primary key and indexed.

```
Indexes:
    "location_history_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (uid, geohash)
    "ix_location_history_geohash" btree (geohash)
    "ix_location_history_uid" btree (uid)
```

But when I query the data by the following constraints, it runs really slow (169 seconds!) even the two columns are already indexed:

```
EXPLAIN (analyze, verbose, buffers) SELECT * FROM location_history WHERE uid = 123 AND geohash >= 'hzzzzzzzzzz';
                                                                            QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using location_history_pkey on public.location_history  (cost=0.71..84735.92 rows=22438 width=29) (actual time=1.434..114713.751 rows=189319 loops=1)
   Output: created_at, updated_at, uid, geohash, is_from_zenly
   Index Cond: ((location_history.uid = 123) AND ((location_history.geohash)::text >= 'hzzzzzzzzzz'::text))
   Buffers: shared hit=5822 read=179864 dirtied=132 written=19338
   I/O Timings: read=111433.601 write=2564.930
 Query Identifier: -7646491345250917333
 Planning Time: 0.103 ms
 Execution Time: 114746.908 ms
(8 rows)
```

And here is the result from `pgstattuple()`:

```
SELECT * FROM pgstattuple(416708);
  table_len   | tuple_count |  tuple_len   | tuple_percent | dead_tuple_count | dead_tuple_len | dead_tuple_percent | free_space | free_percent
--------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+------------------+----------------+--------------------+------------+--------------
 812873588736 | 15570800464 | 685124233392 |         84.28 |             1506 |          66264 |                  0 |  394834592 |         0.05
(1 row)
```

The bloat_ratio is about 34%:

```
SELECT 100-(pgstatindex('location_history_pkey')).avg_leaf_density;

      ?column?
--------------------
 34.260000000000005
(1 row)
```

Could you share any tips to speed up the query? Thanks.

Comment: How many rows are in the table in total? How much ram does the server have?

Comment: @kometen more than 10 billion rows now, and the RAM is 128GiB (an AWS db.m6i.8xlarge instance)

Comment: If you've had many updates/deletion, it might be worth reindexing + vacuum analyze. What is "geohash" (it's fairly unusual to have `>=` on text)?

Comment: Could you please share the results from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers) for this statement? That gives you details about the query plan, the execution and why things are as fast/slow as they are.

Comment: @Bruno There are only INSERT and SELECT on this table. The `geohash` is a 7-digit string like `dr5rfk7` to represent a location (https://geohash.softeng.co/dr5rfk7)

Comment: I'd try a couple of things. (1) With a reasonably modern version of PostgreSQL, partition the table, at least by `uid` (range or hash for example). (2) I wonder if `>=` is efficient on text, so it might be worth converting into an int. If I'm not mistaken, each alphanumerical character in `geohash` represents 5 bits: the whole should easily fit into a 64-bit integer (conversion should be easy if they're all 7-char long).

Comment: @FrankHeikens Sure, I will run the EXPLAIN and update the original post after the traffic spike is over. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Bruno (1) We have already started working on partitioning, but before that, we would like to try to see if we can optimize the index. (2) OK, will give it a try, thanks!

Comment: @FrankHeikens I have updated the original post to include to result of explain(analyze, verbose, buffers), thanks!

Comment: IO is pretty slow, just a few MB per second. Check pgstattuple to see if you have index bloat: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgstattuple.html

Comment: How many different uid's are there? With fewer uid's an index becomes less useful as well, the query planner can resort to a table-scan in some cases.

Comment: @kometen Not sure it's possible **not** to have an index on `(uid, geohash)`, since it's the primary key. The index on `geohash` only is there, but not used.

Comment: @kometen uid is about 10 millions

Comment: @FrankHeikens I've updated the post with the result from `pgstattuple()`. I'm new to index bloat, can you tell me if the results indicate index bloat? If yes, is the next step I need to do to "REINDEX"? Thanks.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I've also included the `bloat_ratio` which is 34%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get a big improvement if you had an index only scan, which you could by including in the index all the columns needed by the query, apparently `(uid, geohash, is_from_zenly, created_at, updated_at)`.  In that case it would only need to visit the index pages and not the (randomly scattered) table pages, as long as the table was well vacuumed.  You could get that "covering" index without partially duplicating the primary key index by doing:

```
alter table location_history add constraint location_history_pkey primary key (uid, geohash) include (is_from_zenly, created_at, updated_at)
```

Of course you would need to drop the current primary key first, so that would entail some downtime.  You could instead just create the new index and live with the redundant indexes.

Of course if your real set of queries can contain more columns than just the ones you showed in your example, this might not be a very complete solution.